# Use Jquery to display a specific JSON object

Tags: jquery, json

Hoping for some help with my coding.

I am attempting to some jquery coding to pull out specific objects from a JSON response i get from a online weather api.

Here is the JSON response i get from the code:

```
{
"coord":
{
    "lon": -4.53,
    "lat": 55.64
},
"sys":
{
    "message": 0.0069,
    "country": "GB",
    "sunrise": 1388306829,
    "sunset": 1388332429
},
"weather": [
{
    "id": 501,
    "main": "Rain",
    "description": "moderate rain",
    "icon": "10n"
}],
"base": "cmc stations",
"main":
{
    "temp": 281.63,
    "pressure": 997,
    "humidity": 87,
    "temp_min": 281.15,
    "temp_max": 282.15
},
"wind":
{
    "speed": 8.7,
    "deg": 170
},
"rain":
{
    "3h": 11
},
"clouds":
{
    "all": 40
},
"dt": 1388357400,
"id": 2645605,
"name": "Kilmarnock",
"cod": 200
}
```

With the JSON response above i was trying to capture both GB within sys/country and Rain within weather/main.

Here the code i have been using:

```
<script> jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
$.ajax({ 
url : "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=55.6409921&lon=-4.5282146", 
dataType : "jsonp", 
success : function(parsed_json) { 
var locations = parsed_json['name'],
    country = parsed_json['sys.country']
main = parsed_json['weather.main'];


var min = parsed_json['sys.country'];

alert("Current locaiton is " + locations );
alert("Current country is " + country);  
alert("Current weather is " + main );
console.log('<p>'+country+'</p>');
console.log('<p>'+main+'</p>'); 
} }); });
```

While i have been messing with the code the location works but for country and main i either get [Object object] and undefined, so at this point i dont have a clue.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sys.country` is not the key, you need to access `country = parsed_json.sys.country`

`parsed_json['sys.country']` looks for an key `sys.country` in the `parsed_json` object, where as you want the value of key `country` inside the object `sys`

Also note that weather is an array, so you need to access the `main` property using an index like `main = parsed_json.weather[0].main`

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v2BxR/)

Comment: Thanks that help solve the problem and your explanation help me understand the code abit better.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `country = parsed_json['sys']['country']` or `parsed_json.sys.country`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `country = parsed_json.sys.country`